# Divide number into digits and save them in list (array) using python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numbers, digits

I want to divide number into digits and save them in list (or array) in python. So firstly I should create list like

```
dig = [0 for i in range(10)]
```

and then

```
i = 0
while num > 9:
    dig[i] = num % 10
    i += 1
    num /= 10
dig[i] = num
```

But I don't really like just creating list for 10 spaces, is it possible to get length of number without repeating loop

```
i = 0
num2 = num
while num2 > 9:
    num2 /= 10
    i += 1
i += 1
```

and then repeat first part of code? Or just make as I made in first place? I don't know exact length of number but it won't be very long

So any advices? Maybe you know better way to divide numbers into digits, or maybe something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're just adding the digits from smallest to greatest in order, just use an empty list:

```
dig = []
i = 0
while num > 9:
    dig.append(num % 10)
    i += 1
    num /= 10
dig.append(num)
```

Alternatively, just do

```
dig = list(int(d) for d in str(num))
```

Which will turn i.e. `123` into `'123'` then turn each digit back into a number and put them into a list, resulting in `[1, 2, 3]`.

If you want it in the same order as your version, use

```
dig = reversed(int(d) for d in str(num))
```

If you really just want to get the length of a number, it's easiest to do `len(str(num))` which turns it into a string then gets the length.

Comment: it maybe small difference but anyway, if numbesr very big and you have a lot of them, which method is more optimal, that one with loop, mod, div, or just list(int(d) for d in str(num)?

Comment: The division version is 400x faster than the string version.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `num` is a positive integer, the number of digits is equal to `int(math.log10(num) + 1)`.

But better than that is to just use the `append` method of `list` -- then you won't have to know the length beforehand.

Even easier (though the list will be in reverse order):

```
dig = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
```

or

```
dig = map(int, str(num))
```

Comment: Good point, I misread it. Bah, you deleted it, no comment upvote for you.

Answer (score 2):

Although `map` is often said to be unpythonic, this task is definitely for it:

```
>>> d = 123456
>>> map(int, str(d))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```